# why the xcode build app for the i386 architecture when the build active architecture only is set to no in debug?

Tags: ios, xcode

I got a third party library which not support to i386 , so in debug mode when  build active architecture only is set to NO, xcode will build fail for i386. But in release configuration , i also set  build active architecture to no , it seems it will not build for the i386.so the app will build success.what's the reason in it? How the xcode judge whether to build for i386 or not?